# vcpkg using local install of boost instead of vcpkg install

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, vcpkg

I am trying to build with cmake and vcpkg. I installed some packages including boost (iostreams, serialization and system) with vcpkg. Additionally, I have a local install of boost without these components. When i try to build, I get the following error:

```
C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2344 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/boost/vcpkg-cmake-wrapper.cmake:11 (_find_package)
C:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:770 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:168 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

The `CMakeCache.txt` has the following line:

```
//Path to a file.
Boost_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=C:/boost/boost_1_66_0
```

which is the path to my local install. How can I get cmake to use the boost install from vcpkg?

EDIT:
To anoyone coming to this question in the future, I came across [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/17336) PR where they apparently fixed the problem. However, I still get the same error when installing OpenMVS.

Comment: You may try to specify `BOOST_ROOT` or `Boost_DIR` on the CMake command line, i.e. `cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=<your_boost_vcpkg_dir>` ... and delete the `CMakeCache.txt` file  before rerunning CMake.

Comment: Unfortunately, vcpkg does not have a boost root directory as far as I know. Rather, each subcomponent has its own directory.

Comment: Delete cache and reconfigure.